# How to generate new random numbers for each function reference?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm coding a little text-based game in Python to help learn the language better, but I'm having an issue where the random attack number is always the same whenever I call the attack function. I want the damage to obviously be different for each attack. Here is the code:

```
health = 100
enhealth = random.randint(1, 20)
charattack = random.randint(0, 10)
enemychance = random.randint(0, 6)
healthpotion = random.randint(1, 20)


def intro():
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print('You are a lone survivor of a plane crash')
    print('Your goal: survive.')
    time.sleep(1)
    print()
    print('\\\\\\\\\\\\')
    print('SURVIVOR')
    print('\\\\\\\\\\\\')
    print()
    time.sleep(1)


def main():
    print("Starting...")
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        start = input("Would you like to play the game? (y/n): ")
        if start.lower() == "y":
            print("Then we begin...")
        elif start.lower() == "n":
            print("Exiting game now...")
            sys.exit()
    except ValueError:
        print("You did not enter a valid option.")


def character():
    global health
    health -= enemychance
    time.sleep(1)
    print('\nYou now have', health, 'health points!\n')
    if health <= 0:
        print("You died! Game Over.")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        pass


def enattack():
    chanceattack = enemychance
    if 0 < chanceattack < 3:
        print('Enemy hit for', chanceattack, 'damage!')
        time.sleep(1)
        character()
    elif chanceattack > 3:
        print('Enemy hit a critical strike for', chanceattack, 'damage!')
        time.sleep(1)
        character()
    else:
        print('Enemy missed!\n')


def enemy():
    global enhealth
    print('\nThe enemy has', enhealth, 'health points!')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Rolling for enemy attack...')
    time.sleep(1)
    enattack()
    if charattack == 0:
        print('You missed!')
    else:
        print("You attack for", charattack, 'damage!')
        time.sleep(1)
        enhealth = enhealth - int(charattack)
    if enhealth > 0:
        print('The enemy now has', enhealth, 'health')
    time.sleep(1)
    if enhealth <= 0:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('You killed the enemy!')
        loot()
    else:
        print()
        cont = input('Attack again? (y/n): ')
        if cont == 'y':
            enemy()
        elif cont == 'n':
            pass


def attack():
    print()
    attacken = input('Attack? (y/n): ')
    if attacken == 'y':
        enemy()
    elif attacken == 'n':
        print('You spared the enemy.')


def loot():
    global health
    lootlist = ['wood sword', 'wood shield', 'fur', 'nothing', healthpotion]
    item = random.choice(lootlist)
    time.sleep(2)
    print('You received', item)
    if item == healthpotion:
        health += healthpotion
    else:
        pass
```

in particular, this is the function that does the player attack:

```
def enemy():
    global enhealth
    print('\nThe enemy has', enhealth, 'health points!')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Rolling for enemy attack...')
    time.sleep(1)
    enattack()
    if charattack == 0:
        print('You missed!')
    else:
        print("You attack for", charattack, 'damage!')
        time.sleep(1)
        enhealth = enhealth - int(charattack)
    if enhealth > 0:
        print('The enemy now has', enhealth, 'health')
    time.sleep(1)
    if enhealth <= 0:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('You killed the enemy!')
        loot()
    else:
        print()
        cont = input('Attack again? (y/n): ')
        if cont == 'y':
            enemy()
        elif cont == 'n':
            pass
```

i'm thinking maybe I just have to do the random calculation inside the function, but is there an easier way? or maybe doing a random function on its own?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I just have to do the random calculation inside the function" - yes, of course. Currently `enemychance` is a constant that you generated _once_ and never change during the execution of the program.

Comment: Yes, you answered your own question

Answer (score 2):

Inside the function is fine and probably the normal way you would do this, since the way you do it now you only do the random generation once at the start and then keep reusing that value.

But certainly if you put these into their own functions it would get more readable. Like a method `get_random_enhealth()` which generates the random number. You could keep the lower limit and upper limit in your variable declarations so it still is easiely accessible/changable.

Edit: Also I don't think the input question does what you think it does on a wrong input (not sure how you call the main though). There won't be a ValueError, it just checks the two ifs, both are False then it continues in the next line (and skips the except block). So the `print("You did not enter a valid option.")` would never be called, the program would probably just end. Try to use a while loop for the input like this:

```
start = input("Would you like to play the game? (y/n): ")
while start.lower() not in ["y", "n"]:
    start = input("You did not enter a valid option.")
if start.lower() == "y":
    print("Then we begin...")
elif start.lower() == "n":  # optionally just 'else:'
    print("Exiting game now...")
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: this does seem quite obvious now that i think about it...i appreciate the answer!!!
and yeah, the try/except was me testing to see if i could get it to work...which i couldnt. i just left it there for now cuz it doesnt break the program